# How to exactly compute percentage change with NaN in DataFrame for each day?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to compute a daily percentage change for this DataFrame (frame_):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data_ = {
    'A':[1,np.NaN,2,1,1,2],
    'B':[1,2,3,1,np.NaN,1],
    'C':[1,2,np.NaN,1,1,2],
       }
dates_ = [
    '06/01/2018','05/01/2018','04/01/2018','03/01/2018','02/01/2018', '01/01/2018'
    ]

frame_ = pd.DataFrame(data_, index=dates_, columns=['A','B','C'])
```

The issue is that I get a DataFrame with this method:

```
returns_ = frame_.pct_change(periods=1, fill_method='pad')

dates,A,B,C
06/01/2018,,,
05/01/2018,,1.0,1.0
04/01/2018,1.0,0.5,
03/01/2018,-0.5,-0.6666666666666667,-0.5
02/01/2018,0.0,,0.0
01/01/2018,1.0,0.0,1.0
```

Which is not what I am looking for. And the dropna() method also doesn't give me the result I seek. I would like to compute a value for each day which has value and NaN for the day where there is no value or NaN. For example, on column A: as a percentage change I would like to see

```
dates,A
06/01/2018,1
05/01/2018,
04/01/2018,1.0
03/01/2018,-0.5
02/01/2018,0.0
01/01/2018,1.0
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Why is `df.pct_change(1, fill_method='pad')` not what you are looking for? Because of the first value?

Comment: Yes, I need to use values of 06/01/2018 and 04/01/2018 to compute the daily percentage change. Therefore this method is not correct.

Comment: `df.pct_change(1, fill_method='pad').fillna(df)` should work if I am not missing anything?

Comment: this works, thank you ayhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way, a bit by brute-force.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data_ = {
    'A':[1,np.NaN,2,1,1,2],
    'B':[1,2,3,1,np.NaN,1],
    'C':[1,2,np.NaN,1,1,2],
       }
dates_ = [
    '06/01/2018','05/01/2018','04/01/2018','03/01/2018','02/01/2018', '01/01/2018'
    ]

frame_ = pd.DataFrame(data_, index=dates_, columns=['A','B','C'])
frame_ = pd.concat([frame_, pd.DataFrame(columns=['dA', 'dB', 'dC'])])

for col in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    frame_['d'+col] = frame_[col].pct_change()
    frame_.loc[pd.notnull(frame_[col]) & pd.isnull(frame_['d'+col]), 'd'+col] = frame_[col]

#               A    B    C   dA        dB   dC
# 06/01/2018  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.000000  1.0
# 05/01/2018  NaN  2.0  2.0  NaN  1.000000  1.0
# 04/01/2018  2.0  3.0  NaN  1.0  0.500000  NaN
# 03/01/2018  1.0  1.0  1.0 -0.5 -0.666667 -0.5
# 02/01/2018  1.0  NaN  1.0  0.0       NaN  0.0
# 01/01/2018  2.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  0.000000  1.0
```

Comment: brute-force (my style too :) ) but very efficient and correct for what I am looking for, thank you jp_data_analysis